# Remove quick edit for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, quick-edit

Is it possible to remove the quick edit function for a custom post type?

I have 14 custom taxonomy with hundreds of terms in each and it takes too much time and resource to load all of them into the source-code of the page.

I tried to find a solution using google but most of them just hides the quick edit button, but the code is loaded in the footer by wordpress, so it doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Bulk Actions page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/bulk_actions) in the codex. I believe the proper action to unset is inline. This will remove the "Edit" bulk action, which is actually quick edit.

```
<?php
    function remove_bulk_actions( $actions ){
        unset( $actions['inline'] );
        return $actions;
    }
    add_filter('bulk_actions-custom_post_type_slug','remove_bulk_actions');
?>
```

As for the Quick Edit in each row, look into [manage_{$post_type}_columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns), as you may be able to replace the Title column with your own, and render it how you wish. There are currently no filters to remove Quick edit in the [WP Posts List Table](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L0), so if the replacing of the column does not work, then you will need to create your own [WP list table extension](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) (Great tutorial).

Comment: Thanks! Alternatively, i can change the taxonomy to non-hierarchical when i'm on the post list page, because in that case its going to be an autocomplete input with ajax

Answer (score 13):

To clarify on Eric's post the `add_filter` code needs to have the `screenid` before the custom post type slug. The most common being `bulk_actions-edit-custom_post_type_slug`.

Also, `unset( $actions['inline'] )` does not appear to be an option.

Both `unset( $actions['edit'] )` and `unset( $actions['trash'] )` were all I could find.

Finally, this code removes the Bulk Options Drop Menu Items, it *does not* remove the "Quick Edit" option which appears while hovering over a post.

```
function ssp_remove_member_bulk_actions( $actions, $post ){
     unset( $actions['edit'] );
     return $actions;
}
add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-member','ssp_remove_member_bulk_actions', 10, 2);
```

**THIS CODE Removes Quick Edit (thanks to jfacemyer)**

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions, $post ) { 
     unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
     return $actions;
}
add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,2);
```

**You can also turn off:**

1. edit = `unset($actions['edit']);`
2. trash = `unset($actions['trash']);`
3. view = `unset($actions['view']);`

**To remove everything from the Quick Edit hover options:**

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions, $post ) { 
     unset($actions['edit']);
     unset($actions['trash']);
     unset($actions['view']);
     unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
     return $actions;
}
add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,2);
```

Finally, you can only remove actions based on a Custom Post Type, or even user capabilities:

```
// Based on Post Type
if ($post->post_type=='myposttype') {
    unset($actions['edit']);
}
// Based on User Capability
if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
   unset($actions['edit']);
}
```

Comment: adding unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']); to the function worked for me.

Comment: For beginners please note you will need to add 'global $post;' before your if post type

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer modifies **bulk edit** dropdown, not **post rows**.

The filter you seek is in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php`, line 1342 (WordPress 5.0.2):

```
/**
 * Filters the array of row action links on the Posts list table.
 *
 * The filter is evaluated only for non-hierarchical post types.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param array $actions An array of row action links. Defaults are
 *                         'Edit', 'Quick Edit', 'Restore', 'Trash',
 *                         'Delete Permanently', 'Preview', and 'View'.
 * @param WP_Post $post The post object.
 */
$actions = apply_filters( 'post_row_actions', $actions, $post );
```

This will work:

```
/**
 * This filter modifies "my_post_type" post rows,
 * such as "Edit", "Quick Edit" and "Trash".
 *
 * @param $actions
 * @param $post
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
add_filter('post_row_actions', function($action, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
        // Remove "Quick Edit"
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    }
    return $actions;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: In your bottom example you need to add the parameter count to the `add_filter` function or it'll throw an error: `add_filter('post_row_actions', function($action, $post) { .. }, 10, 2);`

Comment: @Gavin Added, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom post type is hierarchical, the appropriate hook is `page_row_actions`

```php
add_filter('page_row_actions', function($action, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
        // Remove "Quick Edit"
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    }
    return $actions;
}, 10, 2);
```