# Remove Quick edit for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have found this thread about the same thing:
[Remove quick edit for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78211/remove-quick-edit-for-custom-post-type)
But I only managed to remove the Bulk edit option with this.

What I want to do is to hide/remove Quick edit from a custom post type?

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter to the hook named [`post_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/).

Here's a sample code: (make sure to replace `my-cpt` with the actual post type name)

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'my_cpt_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function my_cpt_row_actions( $actions, $post ) {
    if ( 'my-cpt' === $post->post_type ) {
        // Removes the "Quick Edit" action.
        unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    }
    return $actions;
}
```